# Google DataStudio - Change Default Field Period date

Tags: excel, looker-studio

I have more than one date field.

But I would like to choose, which date field will be used by the period.

The period selector is pulling the "Created on" field.

But this field is not useful for me.

I want the period selector to look for the "Schedule_Date" field.

How can I change the origin of the field, of the period selector?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what matters is the table's date range dimension set to 'Schedule_Date' and not to 'Created on' field.

[image]